# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mysqlcppconn.lib' 

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

Hi am using MS visual VC++ 2008

trying to connect mysql though vc++ code..getting this link error still after setting linker input parameter

but now showing the link erro:fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mysqlcppconn.lib'
Set the mysqlcppconn.lib and libmysql.lib in the properties->configuration prperties-> Linker->Input->Additional dependencies.

IS there any way to set the mysqlcppconn.lib ?? any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to go to **Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories** and add the directory that has the MySQL libraries in there so the linker can find them.

Comment: set "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\lib\opt" under VS 2008 project properties " Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories"

Comment: Do you mean it was already set? Or that you updated the Additional Library Directories and it still doesn't work? Do the `.lib` files actually exist in that location?

Comment: yes..it was already set."C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\lib\opt" under this directory path.The files are (libmysql,mysys,mysqlclient,strings,zlib,regex) object file libraraies...i could find the (mysqlcppconn-static,mysqlcppconn) object file libraraies in the following directory "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5\lib\opt"

Comment: Hi femi, i have set the" C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5\lib\opt" Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories .the error disappeared now..thansk a lot for ur help...

Answer (score 0):

you can include lib file programmatically :

## pragma comment(lib, "requiredLibrary.lib")

good luck!

Comment: i have added #pragma comment(lib,"mysqlcppconn.lib") to the stdfx.h file..but no use..still the same error..